# In Linux, What tools should every webserver-admin uses at least once month?

Tags: linux, web-server, command-line-interface

Just starting out, running across a lot of random CMDs, tools, configs, etc.

Moving on from a server setup, in Linux, what tools should every webserver-admin uses at least once month?

Comment: This sounds like a trick question - even if it wasn't intended as one. If you have to log into your webserver every day then you're either doing something wrong or something unusual.

Comment: @Robert_Moir: Just edited the question to be in an attempt to be more clear, my use was more in the sense of "everyday tools" than using the cmd, tools, etc everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the basics (`ls`, `chown`, `chmod`, etc.), `less`, `vim`, and `rsync` are important. But you shouldn't be running them every day, not even `rsync`. Have a decent automated backup plan in place.

Answer (score 1):

logcheck, backup

Answer (score 1):

Often forgotten tools that really help:

- logrotate
- sysstat
- bwm-ng
- tcpdump
- httpry
- htop